# bootstrap wysiwyg: how to get the formatted text on the server side?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, wysiwyg

I am learning Bootstrap and would like to have a wysiwyg editor. I found **bootstrap-wysiwyg**  and want to use it.

http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/

However, I cannot figure out how to get formatted text on the server-side when a form is submitted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found out how to do this. Here is how.

A hidden input or textarea field is needed. This field may have the name attribute set to the name of an object's field. Its name must be something the server-side expects.

Use JQuery to attach a form submit event handler to the form containing the wysiwyg editor. The handler takes the text from the wysiwyg editor and set it as the hidden field's value.

Hope this helps to someone else.

Answer (score 7):

```
<textarea class="textarea" name="mytext" placeholder="Enter text ..." style="width: 810px; height: 200px"></textarea>
```

use val()

```
$('.textarea').wysihtml5();

$('.textarea').val();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs/vNPAJ/3/

you can get it as post

```
request.POST['mytext']
```

Comment: suhail, this is certainly very helpful. How is your example related to  the bootstrap-wysiwyg plugin? Thanks!

Comment: i am sorry i don't get your question correctly. did you checked the jsfiddle(http://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs/vNPAJ/3/)??? it is used with bootstrap-wysiwyg plugin.

Comment: I did look at your setup in jsfiddle when you made your post. I did not see any link to bootstrap-wysiwyg plugin in your external resources. Are we talking about the same plugin http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/?

Comment: https://github.com/mindmup/bootstrap-wysiwyg/ has 210-watch,2879-stars, 417-forks in GITHUB. but https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5/ have 205-watch, 3048-star, 532-fork. looks like jhollingworth might be better. `mindmup` version is very small. but you need to write the html and also you need to include fontawesome, jquery hotkeys. i updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/suhailvs/vNPAJ/4/

Comment: Thanks for the new jsfiddle setup. Are you aware of any way of directly getting formatted text on server-side? I already got a setup (similar to your new example) working, but it a DIV element, not textarea or input.

Comment: i am using jhollingworth version. it is working fine in my project. you just take it as a textarea don't need to care about any thing. the only problem is the dependency of `wysihtml5-0.3.0.js` which is about `332kb`. i am sorry i don't know much about `mindmup` version.

Comment: suhail, i tried jhollingworth and it appears simple and easy to use. Hoever, i notice that it uses iframe and it is not compatiable with other things i have. thanks so much for everything! best.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old thread, but maybe this tips will help others.

As per mentioned by courious1, we need to create a hidden textarea (eg: id=hidden-editor) on our form. 
and pass the value in #editor to our #hidden-editor using javascript below:

```
//-- submit button clicked
$('#submit-btn').click(function(){
    $('#hidden-editor').html(
        $("#editor").html()
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally came up with this solution. Didn't manage to make the onclick work... but the realtime modification is handy. Thanks for the ideas.

```
$('#editor').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
                $('#you_hidden_textarea').html(
                        $("#editor").html()
                );
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is how to get editor content of **[bootstrap-wysiwyg](https://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/)**

Set id to following div in here I have used *editor* as id and I also set a save button.

```
<div id="editor">
      Go ahead&hellip;
    </div>

<a class="btn" data-edit="bold" id="saveBtn" title="Save"><i class="icon-save"></i></a>
```

Then

```
$('#editor').wysiwyg();

$('#saveBtn').on('click',function(){        

       console.log($('#editor').html());

      })
```

Hope this will help someone else in future